# Erro ao criar projeto no Eclipse

Tags: android-eclipse, android-sdk

eu baixei o Android Studio pra programação Android, mas ele demora quase 10min apenas pra abrir/criar um projeto, então tentei ver outros meios e achei o eclipse com android SDK , bom, baixei o sdk tools diretamente do site android studio, mas agora ele só da pra baixar as ferramentas necessárias por linha de comando, e eu nem sabia oq tinha q baixar nem os nomes, então baixei uma versão antiga do sdkmanager e baixei tudo q o eclipse pediu, mas agora quando vou criar um projeto, na hora de finalizar eu clico em finish e não acontece nada, tipo, nada mesmo, clico quantas vezes quiser e não vai, to pensando até em desistir de programar pra android, pq pora, dois programas e nenhum dar certo, pqp em   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
* fotos de minhas versões no sdkmanager (esses são do eclipse, o android studio ta separado e nem achei o sdkmanager dele) e de um erro que aparece ao abrir o eclipse, não tirei foto de quando o projeto não é criado pq não aparece nenhum erro, ele simplesmente não inicia, não importa quantas vezes eu clicar. *

Comment: rapaz tente otimizar o android studio na sua máquina o eclipse já não tem suporte mais ao android, ou seja como você mesmo disse é um ferramenta antiga, e ela não tem o graddle que é essencial para adicionar bibliotecas ao projeto coisa que futuramente você pode necessitar, lá no android studio baixe somente as apis, e emulador baixa android 6.0 ou 7 pra x86, baixe o hawx acelerador de hardwere pro pc, nas primeiras vezes o android stúdio é lento pra abrir mesmo, mas depois ele melhora.

Comment: Cara, recomendo que você insista no Adroid Studio.
Como o Rogers disse, o Eclipse é uma ferramenta antiga e sem suporte, e a utilização do graddle do Android Studio vai ser necessária em algum momento do seu aprendizado.
Os primeiros builds podem ser mais lentos de acordo com a capacidade da máquina mas existem algumas soluções para dar uma agilizada nos build como esta:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171524/how-to-configure-gradle-to-work-offline-using-cached-dependencies

Answer (score -1):

Eu nunca trabalhei com Android Studio mas já trabalhei bastante com o Eclipse, pela minha experiência quando ocorre um erro desses, sem sentido, o melhor é deletar a pasta do eclipse e suas configurações de workspace e instalar tudo novamente. Verifique também se a versão é 32 ou 64 bits e instale a versão de acordo com teu sistema operacional.

Segue alguns links que encontrei para configurar o Android Studio passo a passo:

http://www.devmedia.com.br/criando-ambiente-android-no-eclipse/24621

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x4eb4oAf6_s

No youtube tem muito conteúdo explicando os passos de configuração e instalação. O Eclipse é meio chato de configurar as vezes é necessário muita paciência e persistência.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Eu já desinstalei e instalei dnv e tbm n deu em nada, baixar novamente é meio difícil pq tenho internet de 1MB então fica chato ficar sempre baixando, acho que vou ficar no Android Studio msm, parece ser a unica solução

Comment: Sim, maioria dos devs mobile utiliza o Android Studio mesmo é muito dor de cabeça configurar na mão o eclipse.